# Postfix SMTP Relay Connection Timeout (Mailgun)

Tags: debian, email, postfix, smtp

I am trying to configure a Postfix SMTP relay to Mailgun services, but I keep getting a connection timeout error in my /var/log/mail.log when I try to send a test email. I used this step by step guide: https://restorebin.com/configure-postfix-smtp-relay/ , except I swapped Gmail SMTP with Mailgun SMTP. I am using Debian 10 on the problem vps, but on another server I am running Ubuntu and Mailgun SMTP is working fine, same configuration, outside of the host/DNS name etc.

Error from log: events postfix/smtp[4046]: connect to smtp.mailgun.org[44.231.238.210]:587: Connection timed out

And just as a side note, I have a lemp stack running on this vps with port 80 and 443 open and working without issue. The only filtering I am doing on the server today is: https://github.com/mitchellkrogza/nginx-ultimate-bad-bot-blocker, but I am also running this on my Ubuntu server without issue along side the Mailgun relay.

I am running out of ideas and want to avoid switching back to Ubuntu if possible. Thanks all!

Comment: `1.` Do you have a mailgun account? `2.` mailgun has their own setup and configuration documentation, why would you not use their documentation? - https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api

Comment: Hi - I do have a Mailgun account and all the DNS record checks are green across the board. I've never used this specific piece of documentation because it has always worked great for me the way I was configuring. I will test this out and see if it works. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I've never used swaks. Is it meant to work along side postfix/mailutils? I tried and I get this error: === Trying smtp.mailgun.org:25...
*** Error connecting to smtp.mailgun.org:25:
***     IO::Socket::INET: connect: timeout

Comment: Please show the relevant lines from `main.cf` and `sasl_passwd` (with obvious redactions).  Specifically, make sure what you set for the `relayhost` exactly matches what you entered in `sasl_passwd` and that you did a `postmap sasl_passwd ; postfix reload` after the changes.  Check that `postfix` user has permission to access `sasl_passwd.db`.  Also try doing a `telnet smtp.mailgun.org 587` to check any network issues.  Since it is a VPS, some providers block various mail ports, so although you say a different VPS works fine, is it with the same provider/network?

Comment: It may be a network issue. I tried telnet smtp.mailgun.org 587 , it attempted connecting to a few IP's without success. "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out" Hmmm. The VPS provider for the issue server is Linode and I believe the working one is OVH.

Comment: Most likely your provider is blocking mail ports by default.  Open a support ticket to fix that or use port 2525 which they provide for such situations (see https://www.mailgun.com/blog/which-smtp-port-understanding-ports-25-465-587/).

Comment: 2525 connected instantly, awesome! I will open a ticket with the provider. So back to my other question. Does swaks work along side postfix/mailutils or will it handle everything? Doing some reading as I have never used it. May not even need it if I can go back to my other config with this working port, but if it is simpler to config and use, I may switch to it.

Comment: Depends how you plan to use Mailgun.  swaks is not a MTA and is therefore not a replacement for postfix.  I'd see it more as an equivalent to `mailx` which takes an email from the command line and contacts the mailgun SMTP server directly.  No queueing, handling of retries, etc.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you all for the information and references! I will work to complete my testing and mark an answer once confirmed.

Comment: This worked. Using 2525 for now until they action my support ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many providers (typically consumer ISP’s but also some hosting providers) and most corporate networks have an anti-spam/email policy that is enforced by blocking outgoing mail in their firewall policies.

Typically they will block outgoing traffic on the default smtp port, tcp 25, but other common ports for sending mail such as tcp 587 can be blocked too.

Your options are usually:

- don’t send mail directly from your server/application but use the smtp mail (relay) service that your provider/network offers (that will typically apply some sanity checks, anti virus and anti spam checks, do rate limiting, sender authentication maybe add your corporate disclaimers etc)
- get an exception for your server / application in the firewall policy so that your valid email traffic won’t be blocked
- in some cases: upgrade from a consumer subscription to a business subscription as that often does allow you to run your own services and send mail

In your particular case:

Mailgun offers their services also on another port, tcp 2525, which is typically not blocked for anti-spam reasons and you might be able to use that one instead of port 587 or 25.

Comment: I had the same error using WSL on Windows 10. Using `smtp.mailgun.org:2525` for the server fixed the issue.